# Consolidate header link css and script list

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am building a website and I'm trying to determine if there is a way to combine/consolidate specific files together without combining them into 1 giant file. I'm trying to clean up my pages I hate having to scroll thru my list for example

```
     <!-- My plugins -->
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-selectpicker.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/nouislider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/photorevealer.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/type.js"></script>
```

I want to create a pointer or something similar to just to go something like

```
<link href="js_scripts.lst">
```

and that file is something like

```
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    export js_script
```

that way I can create 1 file for all the css, 1 file for js files, 1 file for google fonts and so on.

Comment: What you can do is make a JS file that loads elements into the HTML page. I'll post how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one file, `links.js`:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script') 
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript") 
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename) 
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}
```

Then call the function for all your files, again in the `links.js` file:

```
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-switch.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-selectorpicker.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/jasny-bootstrap.min.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/nouislider.min.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/photorevealer.js");
loadjscssfile("./assets/js/type.js");
```

And then load the `links.js` file from your `index.html` page:

```
<script src="links.js"></script>
```

And then your files will load!

**Note:** You won't see these links while you're coding, but they'll be on the website if you hit Inspect. It's just tidier when you're coding.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: I keep getting this error thrown
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
from all the js files now

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yea, its the first js calle in the list ( i didnt add it in the example above though)

Comment: No worries. Always glad to help